# Get array of both checked and unchecked state of checkboxes within adapter

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox

I'd create the listview that contain checkbox and textview in each list. The problem which i'm facing is, I'm not able to retrieve the array of both checked and unchecked values from adapter class. I'd attached some sort of code here.
Here is my Adapter class

```
public class MyFacilityAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<T> mFList;
    LayoutInflater mInflate;
    SparseBooleanArray mySaprseBooleanArray;
    ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public MyFacilityAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<T> facilityList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mInflate = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        mySaprseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

        mFList = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.mFList = facilityList;
    }

    /*public ArrayList<T> getCheckeditems() {

        ArrayList<T> tempArray = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mFList.size(); i++) {
            if (mySaprseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                tempArray.add(mFList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return tempArray;
    }*/
    ArrayList<Integer> getAdapterItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mFList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mFList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflate.inflate(R.layout.row_facility, null);
        }

        TextView tvFName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_facilityName);
        tvFName.setText(mFList.get(postion).toString());
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBox);
        chkBox.setTag(postion);
        /*chkBox.setChecked(mySaprseBooleanArray.get(postion));*/
        chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mChkChangedListener);

        return convertView;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener mChkChangedListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) buttonView;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (chk.isChecked()) {
                items.set(chk.getTag(), 1);
            } else {
                items.set(chk.getTag(), 0);
            }
            /*mySaprseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);*/
        }
    };

}
```

I modified code, to [item.set(chk.getTag(), 1)] like that. but as soon as i checked the checkbox it fires an Indexoutofbounds exception. I attached here logcat.

```
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): Process: com.example.homeyapp, PID: 1019
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.example.homeyapp.MyFacilityAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(MyFacilityAdapter.java:95)
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
04-02 01:21:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. 
First put the integer 1 or 0 into SparseBoolean array like:

```
if (chk.isChecked()) {
                mySaprseBooleanArray.put((Integer) chk.getTag(), isChecked);
            } else {
                mySaprseBooleanArray.put((Integer) chk.getTag(), isChecked);
            }
```

then,
In order to get checked and unchecked items array:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getCheckeditems() {

        ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mFList.size(); i++) {
            Boolean temp = mySaprseBooleanArray.get(i);
            if (temp) {
                items.add(1);
            } else {
                items.add(0);
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

here items return as a 100101010; 1 as checked and 0 as a unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

The 'items' ArrayList needs to be pre-populated with the same number of elements as there are rows in your list. (Right now, you are appending a *new* integer element to the ArrayList every time the user checks or unchecks any row -- which makes no sense.)

If you do the above, then onCheckChanged() can look like:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) buttonView;
        if (chk.isChecked()) {
            items.set(chk.getTag(), 1);
        } else {
            items.set(chk.getTag(), 0);
        }
        /*mySaprseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);*/
    }
```

Comment: I modified the code as you said. but still it seems not gud. And How exactly the 'items' can be pre-populated??